# API gateway Missing Authentication Token

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am very new to AWS API and I am trying to invoke a lambda function through API GW and it gives error "Missing Authentication Token" when I invoked the URL from a browser.

What I have created so far is:

```
MyLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Description: >
      Currently does not support S3 upload event.
    Handler: index.handler
    Runtime: nodejs20.x
    FunctionName:
      !Sub
        - "${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-get-v1"
        - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
          TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
    CodeUri: .
    MemorySize: 1028
    Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
    Policies:
      - PolicyName:
          !Sub
          - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-serverless-function-policy"
          - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
    Events:
      MyDemoAPI:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          RestApiId: !Ref MyApiGateway
          Path: /batch
          Method: GET
    Tracing: Active

MyApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name:
      !Sub
      - '${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-api'
      - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
        TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheBucketRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
     StageName: test
    TracingEnabled: true
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.2

MyLambdaExecutionRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName:
      !Sub
      - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-lambda-execution-role"
      - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    Policies:
      - PolicyName:
          !Sub
          - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-lambda-execution-role-policy"
          - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
            TheEnvName: !Ref Environment
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                - 'batch:SubmitJob'
                - 'batch:DescribeJobs'
                - 'batch:CancelJob'
              Resource: "*"
```

My index.js looks like this:

const https = require("https");
let url = "https://aws.amazon.com/";

```
exports.handler = async function (event) {
let statusCode;
await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  https.get(url, (res) => {
      statusCode = res.statusCode;
      resolve(statusCode);
    }).on("error", (e) => {
      reject(Error(e));
    });
});
console.log(statusCode);
return statusCode;
};
```

My lambda and API are deployed successfully, but when I invoke the URL

https://xxxxxrv9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test

I get {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}

When I invoke the URL with the stage part included I get
{"message": "Internal server error"}

https://xxxxxrv9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/batch

Can some one help me understand how should I be calling the API? Appreciate your help.

Comment: 'Missing Authentication Token' is thrown from the authoriser mapped to API gateway. However I don't see any authoriser, stage, method, resource in your script. Can you confirm if you have shared the correct script ?

Comment: Thank you. There is a GET method in MyLambdaFunction. Is that what you're referring to? Am I missing something here? If so in MyLambdaFunction block?

Comment: I just added this to MyApiGateway    
Auth:
DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
  CustomStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action: 'execute-api:Invoke'
      Resource: [ 'execute-api:/api/GET/batch' ]
      Principal:
        AWS:
         - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
but still same error. Not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: The lambda function itself when tested independently from AWS console gets back status code 200(success) from the index.js. But when the same lambda function is invoked from API getting this error: {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:********4688:65mz6veluk/test/GET/batch"}

Comment: Looks like I need to re-create the API when I make changes. Reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html. I had to fully delete my cloudformation stack and re-create it. Is there a way to just update the API whenever I make some changes to it, instead of deleting the stack and re-creating?

Comment: Yes @Ram, just re-deploy the API gateway stage. No need to delete the entire cf stack.

Comment: Thanks Prerak. Is there a CF script I can include as part of my stack to deploy the API. In that way I don't have to manually deploy it from AWS console...

Comment: @Ram Is it resolved ? Or you are still getting error while invoking ? https://xxxxxrv9.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/batch API endpoint ?

Comment: @Manish - Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77681813/err-name-not-resolved-error-when-invoking-api-endpoint-from-react Thanks