# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error when invoking API endpoint from react

Tags: reactjs, docker, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

Please refer to my earlier post [API gateway Missing Authentication Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77667536/api-gateway-missing-authentication-token?noredirect=1#comment136941030_77667536)

I made a change to my logic, where I am now using AWS::Serverless::Function to trigger batch job and this is attached to an API gateway now.

Corresponding CF scripts for this:

```
MyLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Description: >
      Currently does not support S3 upload event.
    Handler: index.handler
    Runtime: nodejs20.x
    FunctionName:
      !Sub
        - "${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-get-v1"
        - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
          TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
    CodeUri: .
    MemorySize: 10240
    Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
    Events:
      MyDemoAPI:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          RestApiId:
            Ref: MyApiGateway
          Path: /batch
          Method: GET
    Tracing: Active
    Tags:
      AppName: !Ref AppNameForTags
      Cost: !Ref CostTagValue

MyApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name:
      !Sub
      - '${TheEnv}-${TheAppNameForResources}-api'
      - TheEnv: !Ref Environment
        TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheBucketRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
    StageName: test
    TracingEnabled: true
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.2
```

The AWS Batch function is a Docker image and I am referring to this image in my ECS.
When I invoke the API endpoint from my browser, the lambda function is executed successfully and starting my batch job.

After this I added a small react app and in that I am referring to my API gateway URL. The react app is accessable via a Load Balancer (Application)
I have a button to trigger the batch job (I mean trigger the lambda function which in turn triggers the batch job).

When I tried to access the react app via ALB DNS, I am getting this error

"You need to enable Javascript to run this app" (Seen from chrome developer tools)

**The earlier error which is the title of this post is gone now after I added
mode: 'no-cors' in TriggerButton.jsx and changed method: POST to method:GET**

This is my code for lambda function and my react app.

```
const { BatchClient, SubmitJobCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-batch"); // CommonJS import
const config = {
         region: "us-east-1",
    };

const batchClient = new BatchClient(config);
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    const params = {
     jobDefinition: "dev-login-test",
     jobName: "test-poc",
     jobQueue: "dev-test-jq-alpha",
   };

try {
    const command = new SubmitJobCommand(params);
    const data = await batchClient.send(command);
    console.log('Job Submitted successfully...', data);
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Job submitted -> ok'),
    };
} catch(error) {
    console.error('Error starting batch job: ', error);
    return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify('Error submitting job: ', error),
    };
  }
};
```

The react code is below:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import TriggerButton from './TriggerButton';

function App(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My React app</h1>
      <TriggerButton /> {/* Render TriggerButton component */}
    </div>
 );
}
```

TriggerButton.jsx code:

```
import React from 'react';
class TriggerButton extends React.Component {
    handleClick = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://wxxxxxxx97.execute-api.us-east- 
      1.amazonaws.com/test/batch", {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          //'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : '*',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : '*',
        },
      });

  if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Lambda function triggered successfully');
        //Add any additional logic or UI changes upon successful execution
    } else {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Failed to trigger Lambda function: ');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle network errors
    console.error('Error triggering Lambda function: ');
  }
};
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Trigger Lambda function</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default TriggerButton;
```

I am not sure what's this error message is indicating. Any help in resolving this much apreciated.
I am not sure if this is a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that it's a CORS issue. You can try a couple of things to be sure if it indeed the case. Try adding the Cors property to your AWS::Serverless::Api,

```js
MyApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Name: ...
    StageName: ...
    TracingEnabled: true
    OpenApiVersion: 3.0.2
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "*" #adjust based on your requirements if needed
      AllowHeaders: "*" #adjust based on your requirements if needed
      AllowOrigin: "'*'" #adjust based on your requirements if needed
```

Include CORS headers in the Lambda function's response as well. While the CORS headers in the API Gateway help with preflight (OPTIONS) requests, including CORS headers in the Lambda function response ensures that the actual request (the GET request) is also handled correctly by the browser.

```js
   // CORS headers
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // adjust based on your requirements if needed
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*", // adjust based on your requirements if needed
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*", // adjust based on your requirements if needed
      },
      body: JSON.stringify('Job submitted -> ok'),
    };

    return response
```

Also you should remove the custom headers from the headers section in your React fetch method. Since you've already configured CORS settings on the server side (API Gateway), you don't need to set the CORS-related headers explicitly in your fetch request from the client side.

Comment: Thank you. I added the Cors to APIGateway resource as mentioned., but the stack didn't create successfully. Getting error: Resource handler returned message: "Errors found during import: Unable to put integration response on 'OPTIONS' for resource at path '/batch': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: *] (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 25f3a9d3-7a3e-4984-baa0-7894146a3afe)" (RequestToken: 6218f329-5a08-b485-728e-b068221ddc70, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest).

Comment: Looks like formatting issue in Cors section. I've this for Cors in my AWS::Serverless::Api
Cors:
  AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
  AllowMethods: "'*'"
  AllowOrigin: "'*'". But I am still unable to access API endpoint from my ALB DNS. Its failing in the else part with my custom msg "Failed to trigger lambda function". In the react code I am accessing const response = await fetch("https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/batch" which is the API endpoint here.

Comment: I think I am able to trigger the batch job from ALB DNS. It was the error msg placed at the wrong caused confusion.